# What's the difference between 「ご飯を食べる」「ご飯を済ます」 and 「ご飯を済ませる」?

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances, word-usage

「ご飯を食べる」「ご飯を済ます」 and 「ご飯を済ませる」, they all mean to finish breakfast/ lunch/ dinner, what's the nuance between them?

I tried to get it out but there are totally different explainings about the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

食べる is just "to eat". It does not have the meaning of "to end/finish" at all. If you want to use 食べる to say "to finish the meal", you have to add 終える and say ご飯を食べ終える (literally "to finish eating the meal").

済ます and 済ませる both mean "to finish". Grammatically, they are two different causative forms of 済む, which is a godan intransitive verb meaning "to come to an end" or "to be finished". That is, ご飯を済ます and ご飯を済ませる both literally mean "to make your meal finished". 済ませる is the normal causative form, and 済ます is a less common short variant. You can read about the two types of causative forms [here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/causepass).